# why process doesn't join and doesn't run?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

i have a simple problem to solve(more or less)
if i watch python multiprocessing tutorials i see that a process should be started more or less like this:

```
from multiprocessing import *

def u(m):
    print(m)
    return

A=Process(target=u,args=(0,))
A.start()
A.join()
```

It should print a 0 but nothing gets printed. Instead it hangs forever at the `A.join()`.

if i manually start the function u doing this

```
A.run()
```

it actually prints 0 on the shell but it doesn't work simultaneously
for example the output of following code:

```
from multiprocessing import *
from time import sleep

def u(m):
    sleep(1)
    print(m)
    return

A=Process(target=u,args=(1,))
A.start()
print(0)
```

should be
0
1

but actually is
0

and if i add before the last line

```
A.run()
```

then the output becomes
1
0

this seems confusing to me...

and if i try to join the process it waits forever.

however,if it can help giving me an answer
my OS is Mac os x 10.6.8
python versions used are 3.1 and 3.3
my computer has 1 intel core i3 processor

--Update--
I have noticed that this strange behaviour is present only when launching the program from IDLE ,if i run the program from the terminal everything works as it is supposed to,so this problem must be connected to some IDLE bug.
But runnung programs from terminal is even weirder: using something like range(100000000) activates all my computer's ram until the end of the program; if i remember well this shouldn't happen in python 3,only in older python versions.
I hope these new informations will help you giving an answer

--Update 2--
the bug occurs even if i don't perform output from my process,because setting this:

```
def u():
    return
```

as the target of the process and then starting it , if i try to join the process,idle waits forever

Comment: I can't tell you why, which is why I didn't post this as an answer, but all the examples of creating processes have no `return` statement in the target (which is different from `Pool` targets).  Have you tried removing the return statement from `u`?

Comment: @sr2222 Nope.`return` is equivalent to `return None`. Modulo control flow (not a concern in OP's example), not having a `return` at all is the same as returning `None`.

Comment: Both your examples give me the expected results on linux on all the python versions that I have installed.

Comment: @delnan, Yeah, I know that for normal cases, but I wasn't sure if down in the bowels of the C-extension `_multiprocess`, `select`, or `fcntl` libraries, there is some subtle difference, and it was being exposed here.

Comment: do you think a bounty could help me finding an answer?

Comment: Are you only experiencing the bug when running from the Python interpreter (I could not exactly tell from your question)?

Answer (score 7):

As suggested [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue13220) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774585/child-processes-created-with-python-multiprocessing-module-wont-print/2774623#2774623), the problem is that IDLE overrides `sys.stdin` and `sys.stdout` in some weird ways, which do not propagate cleanly to processes you spawn from it (they are not real filehandles).

The first link also indicates it's unlikely to be fixed any time soon ("may be a 'cannot fix' issue", they say).

So unfortunately the only solution I can suggest is not to use IDLE for this script...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `A.join()` to your program? I am guessing that your main process is exiting before the child process prints which is causing the output to be hidden. If you tell the main process to wait for the child process (`A.join()`), I bet you'll see the output you expect.

Comment: no,if i try A.join() python interpreter waits forever, and the child process doesn't run as i said in the question

Comment: Sorry, I read the code and didn't realize that's what you meant in the title. I've edited the question itself to include the call to A.join. I will think on this some more.

Answer (score 0):

Given that it only happens with IDLE, I suspect the problem has to do with the stdout used by both processes. Perhaps it's some file-like object that's not safe to use from two different processes.

If you don't have the child process write to stdout, I suspect it will complete and join properly. For example, you could have it write to a file, instead. Or you could set up a pipe between the parent and child.

Comment: even if i give my child process a task like doing some arithmetic,without using input or output,or writing to a file,the taskmanager tells me that only one core of my cpu is in use

Comment: That's not a sensible test. Unless that core is being utilized at or near 100%, there's no reason for another core to be used just because there's another process. The question is: does the child process complete successfully and does the parent's join request succeed?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried unbuffered output?  Try importing the sys module and change the print statement:

```
print >> sys.stderr, m
```

How does this affect the behavior?  I'm with the others that suspect that IDLE is mucking with the stdio . . .